# rotate object 0 to 90 with speed 1 then wait then 90 to 0 degree with 1 speed unity c#

Tags: unity, c#

i want to Rotate my object 0 to 90 degree with 1 speed --> then wait for 3 Sec ---> Then Rotate again 90 to 0 degree with 1 speed --> Then wait for 3 sec

i need above process in loop

i m success with it but it working only 1 time in Start Function

In update function its not working

below my code

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 0f, 1f));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}

IEnumerator RotateMe1(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe2(Vector3 byAngles2, float inTime2)
{
    var fromAngle2 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle2 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles2);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime2)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle2, toAngle2, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Below my Update Function code

```
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
    StartCoroutine(Wait());
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 0f, 1f));
    StartCoroutine(Wait());
}

IEnumerator RotateMe1(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe2(Vector3 byAngles2, float inTime2)
{
    var fromAngle2 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle2 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles2);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime2)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle2, toAngle2, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}
```

[Here i recorded Video for issue of Update Function](https://youtu.be/nxnFzf6Ethk)

i attached above script on AXE in attached above Video

Please help me

Comment: Please don't cross post on other stack exchange sites. Only post on the most appropriate site for your question. If you've posted it and feel like it was a mistake, remove it first, then post it at different site.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Tweening` engine like `DOTween`: http://dotween.demigiant.com/

Then, you create a script like `TestRotation` and achieve your rotation in 3 lines of code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;

public class TestRotation : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){
        Sequence sequence = DOTween.Sequence(); // create a sequence
        sequence.Append(this.transform.DORotate(new Vector3(90f, 0f, 0f), 1f).SetDelay(3f)); // rotate it by 90 on X axis for 1 second, and delay it for 3 seconds
        sequence.SetLoops(-1); // repeat continously
    }

}
```

Tweening makes the life 300% easier, really.

Comment: *`Tweening makes the life 300% easier, really.`* And so many people who respond "ew, plugins, I wanna do it myself for the EXPEREUNCE."

Comment: Getting into Unity without knowledge about OOP and particular languages on at least intermediate level is a waste of time ;>

Answer (score 0):

In RotateMe2 you have this line:
`var toAngle2 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles2);`

The current `transform.eulerAngles` is (90,0,0).  The byAngles2 (passed to the function from Start) is (0,0,0).

(90,0,0) + (0,0,0) = (90,0,0).

Surprise, nothing changes when you attempt to rotate.  You've confused *byAngles* with *toAngles.*

Also, RotateMe1 and RotateMe2 are identical, except with differently named paramter and local variables names. So there's really no reason for it at all.

Corrected code:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * -90f, 1f));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}
```

Comment: i already tried (Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f) & (Vector3.forward * -90f, 1f) but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single coroutine to do the job, use it instead.
Basically, this.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
}

IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
        var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
        for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        byAngles1 *= -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i got Answer from @Programmer in Stackoverflow.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(rotateForever());
}

IEnumerator rotateForever()
{
    while (true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * -90f, 1f));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe1(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe2(Vector3 byAngles2, float inTime2)
{
    var fromAngle2 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle2 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles2);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime2)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle2, toAngle2, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

just need to do in repeat forever.